# scroll using window scroll position is not always equal to the difference in document size minus window size

Tags: scroll

I am trying to create a scroll pagination system but I am facing a problem:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) == $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
                

        $.ajax({
            url: "loadit.php?id=" + $('.post:last').attr('id'),
            
            beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#loader').show();
            },
            
            success: 
                function (html) {

                    $('#loader').show();

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        if(html){
                            $('#comments').append(html);
                            $('#loader').hide();
                        }else{
        
                            $('#loader').hide();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                    
                }
           
        });
    }
```

$(window) .scrollTop ()) == $ (document) .height () - $ (window) .height ()

This equality is not always true because there is a slight margin of sensitivity and that makes it so that I am unable to execute the rest of my code.

Even when I use Math.floor or ceil, it doesn't solve the problem at some scroll level.

Could someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, so `scrollTop` can be used to determine the vertical scroll position. document height is the height of the entire document, while window height is the height of the viewport (the browser window), so they are separate values...

Comment: Yes I know, but the equality must be verified, right? Since I'm trying to reproduce an exo using this equality to enter the condition :